# How to get all the element's Ids and value of the form?

Tags: jquery

I have following form

```
<form id = "form" method = "post" ...>
  <select id = "companies" name="companies" multiple="multiple">
    <option value = "1"> ...</option>
    <option value = "2"> ... </option>
    ...
  </select>
  <input id = "count" ...>
   ....
</form>
```

I am trying to get all the form's elements ids. I tried following in jquery

```
var $ids = $("#form input[id]").each(function() {
    alert($(this).filter(":input"));
 });
alert($ids);
```

Now my problem is I can't get the `listbox id` if I didn't select any company from the options.

How can I get the `id` of `listbox` even the option is not selected?

TIA

Comment: What is the point for downvote? Don't just downvote and leave. Please leave some reason for downvote so that will help me to ask better question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because you have used the input [element selector](http://api.jquery.com/element-selector/) - it will not select `select` or `textarea` elements. You can try the [:input-selector](http://api.jquery.com/input-selector/) (may not give the best performance)

Try

```
var ids = $("#form :input[id]").map(function () {
    return this.id
}).get();
alert(ids);
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/7f5xq/)

---

For a better performance try

```
var ids = $("#form").find('input[id], select[id], textarea[id]').map(function () {
    return this.id || undefined
}).get();
console.log(ids);
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/r4Ydf/)

Comment: before closing this topic how can I get the `value` also?

Comment: @Lakhae how do you want the data structure to be

Comment: I am trying to find the ids that don't have value. In my case if `id = company value =""` then I need to add some logic here if the value is empty.

Comment: @Lakhae what kind of data structure you are looking for an array/object

Comment: i am looking for object but it doesn't matter.